# Using strpos to locate a particular substring and store the following (PHP)

Tags: php, moodle

I have the values of a Database query stored in a `$domains`. Each record looks like so: `domain_23`, `domain_88`, `domain_0` etc.

For each of the values, I would like to extract the number after the underscore and store it in a variable called `$dom_id`. How can I achieve this? Here is my attempt:

```
foreach($domains as $domain)
{       
    if (strpos($domain, "_")) {
        $domain = $dom_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Relating to the question you've just deleted, you may want to take a look at this question and the accepted answer... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 2):

you can use `explode`:

```
foreach ($domains as $domain)
{
    if (strpos($domain, '_')) {
        $domainArr = explode('_', $domain);
        $domainNum = $domainArr[1]; # should output number

        # and if you want it as an int
        $domainNum = (int) $domainNum;
    }
}
```

as IncredibleHat rightly said, this is for domains with values like `domain_4`  - this won't work for something like `domain_thats_cool_4` - but we can make more dynamic like this:

```
$domainNum = end($domainArr); # should output number
```

ref:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Comment: The only danger here... is if for some reason the first part has more than 1 underscore (his examples were very basic). Like if his domains are: `_tcp.gmail.com_88` etc

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. All domains will follow the same format with just one underscore so there is no reason to account for different scenarios. I am receiving the following error: PHP Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: @D0uble0 then $domain is an object, print_r($domain) inside the loop to see what data is there

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the offset returned from `strpos` and then use `substr`:

```
foreach ($domains as $domain) {
  if (($offset = strpos($domain, '_')) && $offset !== false) {
    $dom_id = substr($domain, $offset);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use regular expressions for this:

```
foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    if (preg_match('!_(\d+)$!', $domain, $matches)) {
        $dom_id = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this: You can be sure that only numbers after an underscore at the end of the string will be matched.

On the other hand, Regular Expressions are quite dense and not every programmer is familiar with them, so your mileage may vary.